# Wonderware Historian Ver 10: Transfer data from old tagname to new tagname

Tags: sql-server-2008, tagname, historian, wonderware

Is it possible to transfer old historized data from an object/attribute tagname to a new object/attribute tagname?

My client uses Archestra 2009 to measure various pressures and temperatures. They historize their data for review and safety reasons. This data is stored and can be looked at via MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

A couple years ago I developed a Valve Statistics Report where it would read in historized valve state data. This report is created on Visual Studio 2008 and references a stored procedure to retrieve the data and build the report. The process was if a suction valve triggered from a Close to Open state then it would retrieve a certain set of pressure, temperature, and gas flow readings.

Let us call one of these SuctionPressure101.SuctPressReading. SuctionPressure101 is the object in Archestra and SuctPressReading is an analog attribute within the object. When you reference the historian and look up SuctionPressure101.SuctPressReading then you would retrieve data from any time range that is between its created historized moment to the current time.

The client upgraded some of their programming and changed the name from SuctionPressure101.SuctPressReading to SuctionPressure101.PV instead. SuctionPressure101.PV is now historized but here is the dilemma.

The report is looking at the old tag thus returning blank or NULL via stored procedure since it no longer exists if viewed anytime after its alteration. I can easily update the stored procedure and involved tables to reference the new tagname but the price is that the client will no longer be able to reference the old tagname for record purposes. I could also have both exist in the report but the old or the new tagname would be null and the other would display data. That may be the solution but I wanted to know if this route exists instead:

Is it possible to transfer or "Copy-paste" the old data from SuctionPressure101.SuctPressReading into SuctionPressure101.PV so that it may hold old and new data thus the report looks cleaner and seamless?

That way SuctionPressure101.PV can show data that existed from SuctionPressure101.SuctPressReading and also its historized data.

Comment: Not sure how programming related...

Comment: Not programming persay but more like structure after the programming has been established. I figured to ask if anyone in the community has experience with Wonderware programming or software and would know something like this

Comment: So... it's not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

The client needs to request information from a local distributor or system integrator on how to preserve old tag data when renaming tags.. They will probably receive the "Historian Server Tag Rename Utility", which can be used to point the old data to the new tagname.